# C# Entity Framework, adding data to database with Many-to-Many connections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I'm quite new to programming and very new to databases. I've used CodeFirst approach to make a local database.
[Database model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCxyP.png)

The code for Work class is:

```cs
public class Work
    {
        public int WorkId{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public int SalaryMinimum { get; set; }
        public int SalaryMaximum { get; set; }
        public string Education { get; set; }
        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        public virtual List<WorkCondition> WorkCondition { get; set; }
    }
```

The code for WorkCondition class is:

```cs
 public class WorkCondition
    {
        public int WorkConditionId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description{ get; set; }
        public virtual List<Work> Work { get; set; }
    }
```

DbContext code, that makes Many-to-Many relationship:

```cs
 public class CrmDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public CrmDbContext() : base("name=CrmSQL") { }
        public DbSet<Client> Client { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Work> Work { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WorkCondition> WorkCondition {get; set;}
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Work>()
                        .HasMany<WorkCondition>(wc => wc.WorkCondition)
                        .WithMany(w => w.Work)
                        .Map(wwc =>
                        {
                            wwc.MapLeftKey("WorkId");
                            wwc.MapRightKey("WorkConditionId");
                            wwc.ToTable("WorkWorkCondition");
                        });

        }
    }
```

After "enable-migartion", "add-migration Initial" and "update-database" EF made a table  WorkWorkCondition that manages Many-To-Many relationship, there are two columns: WorkConditionId and WorkId.

So far my code for adding new Work looks like this:

```cs
using (var db = new CrmDbContext())
{
    var work1 = new Work
    {
        Name = "Tech Play add 2",
        Start = DateTime.Now,
        End = DateTime.Now,
        SalaryMinimum = 2000,
        SalaryMaximum = 3000,
        WorkCondition = new List<WorkCondition>(),
        ClientID = 2
    };
    //WorkConditionId = 1 and WorkConditionId = 3 have to be associated with 
    //this new work 
    db.Work.Add(work1);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

So, my problem is that I can't understand how to insert data, so that EF fills WorkWorkCondition table automatically. In my case I'd like to add new Work, that have multiple WorkConditions. WorkConditions is filled with 3 row and I'd like to refer them by WorkConditionId.

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but have you tried filling out your List<WorkCondition> with work conditions from the database?

Comment: Think of an database as one excel worksheet.  The tables in the database are groups of columns in the worksheet (are views of the database).  So table I can contain columns A, B, C.  table II can contain columns A, D, E.  Table III can contain Columns A, F, G.   When you insert data or changing data you are effecting one or more rows of the datasheet.  So you have to use a where statement to specify the rows you need to add and the table aren't important because they are just views of the database.

Comment: Simple add list of work conditions in work's WorkCondition property and please change it to WorkConditions due to m:m relationship.

Comment: Thank you guys, I've added desired work conditions to the list and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this code, definetly not the pretiest one, but it worked for me.

```
using (var db = new CrmDbContext())
{
    List<WorkCondition> wc2 = new List<WorkCondition>();
    wc2.Add(db.WorkCondition.Where(wcid => wcid.WorkConditionId == 3).SingleOrDefault());
    wc2.Add(db.WorkCondition.Where(wcid => wcid.WorkConditionId == 1).SingleOrDefault());

    var work1 = new Work
    {
        Name = "Tech Play add 2",
        Start = DateTime.Now,
        End = DateTime.Now,
        SalaryMinimum = 2000,
        SalaryMaximum = 3000,
        WorkCondition = wc2
    };
    db.Work.Add(work1);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```